# Is there a way filter a data-frame based on values in column x that occurred previously?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a dataframe based so that i preserve the entire row if its value in column X hasn't occurred before. If it has occurred before I need it to compare the value in column Y to the value in column Y in the first row.

example:

```
MM     Bid Sz      Bid      

BP1     15       73.20
TWD1    15       73.15
SPAC    250      71.00
BCOM1   500      71.00
BP2     500      71.00
TWD2    500      71.00
BP3     250      71.00
MC1     500      71.00
MC2     275      70.25
TWD3    275      70.10
MC3     150      68.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.drop_duplicates`. In your example, if you want to drop the rows that have a `Bid` value that is witnessed in a prior row, you would call `<your_dataframe>.drop_duplicates(subset="Bid")`. Here, the `keep` keyword argument has default value `"first"`, which is the behavior you want, so there's no need to set it.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

I may need more information to solve your problem, but hopefully this will get you going.

Here I made a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': [1,1,2,3,4,5], 'Y':['kept', 'dropped', 2, 3, 4, 5]}); df
```

which looks like this ...

```
X   Y
1   kept
1   dropped
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

I then dropped the non-unique values in `df['X']`, and `kept` the `'first'` appearance of the value:

`df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X'], keep='first');df`

So now, my `df` looks like this:

```
X   Y
1   kept
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

Using `drop_duplicates` you can ensure that only the unique values in a row are kept to at least some logical degree. However, you may also want to consider looping over the data frame with `iterrows` to check for unique values and do your comparison at the same time. This would greatly help with efficiency.

In the end, if this was not what you're looking for, please let me know and/or provide more information. I'll be happy to help!